# Creating my view for multiple screens android

Tags: android, xml, screen

I have a problem to display my view on different screen size. [image]

My attached view is not fully visible in 3.2 inch screen but ok with 3.7 inch screen. I have described the sml contents in the image itself. Please suggest a solution.

Normally what is ideal way of doing things for multiple screens? Does android have adusting it automatically for different screen sizes?

Answer (score 1):

make your `linearLayout` height `fillparent` :

```
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
```

and of course your scrollview must have a relative height .

But...

The way i would do that , is the next:

> RelativeLayout
>   -scrollview
>   -LinearLayout (with button)

Then put first in your xml your linearLayout , width an fixed height , then make the `android:layout_below="@+id/LinearLayoutId"` in the scrollView . After that put the 
`android:layout_height="fill_parent"` in the scrollView , finalizing putting the LinearLayout `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"`

Answer (score 0):

One good approach is to use layout_weight to tell Android which parts of the layout should be stretched to fit the screen in what proportions.  You should also use layout_width, layout_height set to fill_parent to size your main LinearLayout to fit the screen.

Answer (score 0):

You can use 2 things

`weightSum` in the Main LinearLayout

and `layout_weight` in the child Layouts.

That Will Work for You.